# Stop raspbian/debian from within python

Tags: python, linux, raspbian

When I am away from my mountain, I monitor my Photo-voltaic system with Raspberry Pi and a small python script to read data and send it to my web page every hour.  That is launched by a electo-mechanical switch that lights up the stuff for 15 minutes.  But during that period, the script may run twice, which I would like to prevent as the result is messy (lsdx.eu/GPV_ZSDX).

I want to add some line at the end of the script to stop it once it has run once and possibly stop raspbian as well for a clean exit before the power is off.
- "exit" only exits a loop but the script is still running
- of course Ctrl+C won't do as I am away;
Could not find any tip in these highly technical messages in StackOverflow or in Rasbian help either.

Any tip?
Thanks

Comment: It would be nice of you to show us what you've tried thus far? Why it didn't work. Coming to SO just to get someone else to solve problems without trying yourself first is, well it's not very nice. So for instance, if you want to shut down your RPi, why not try `os.system('shutdown -hP now')` or something similar?

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular programming problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Answer (score 0):

The `exit()`  command should exit the program (`break` is the statement that will exit a loop). What behavior are you seeing?

To shut down , try :

python3:

```
from subprocess import run
run('poweroff', shell=True)
```

python2:

```
from subprocess import call
call('poweroff')
```

Note: poweroff may be called shutdown on your system and might require additional command line switches to force a shutdown (if needed).

Answer (score 0):

For your case, structure the python script as a function using the following construct:

```
def read_data():
    data_reading_voodo
    return message_to_be_sent

def send_message(msg):
    perform_message_sending_voodo
    log_message_sending_voodoo_success_or_failure
    return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    msg = read_data()
    send_message(msg)
```

Structured like this, the python script should exit after running.

Next create a shell sript like follows (assuming bash and python, but modify according to your usage)

```
#!/bin/bash
python -m /path/to/your/voodo/script && sudo shutdown -h 6
```

The `sudo shudown -h 6` shuts down the raspberrypi 6 minutes after the script is run. This option helps so you have some time after startup to remove the sript if you ever want to stop the run-restart cycle.

Make the shell script executable: `chmod 755 run_py_script_then_set_shutdown` see `man chmod` for details

Now create a cronjob to run `run_py_script_then_set_shutdown` on startup.

`crontab -e` Then add the following line to your crontab

```
@reboot /path/to/your/shell/script
```

Save, reboot the pi, and you're done.
Every time the rpi starts up, the python script should run and exit. Then the rpi will shutdown 6 minutes after the python script exits.

You can (should) adjust the 6 minutes for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all these answers that help me learn Pyth and Deb.
I finally opted for a very simple solution at the end of the script:
    import os
    os.system('sudo shutdown now')

But I keep in mind these other solutions
Thanks again,
Lionel